# Unlock bitlocker drive with VBScript

Tags: methods, vbscript, wmi

I'm trying to script out the unlocking of a bitlocker drive using a DRA certificate. I'm attempting to use the WMI Method UnlockWithCertificateFile and I can't for the life of me figure out what i'm doing wrong or even find an example.

I know the certificate and pin work because i can manually unlock the drive using manage-bde -unlock....

when i run my script i get a return value of -2146885623 wich i've looked up to be -2146885623,     "Cannot find the requested object."

i'm not sure what object its talking about.

here is the code i'm using (minus the pin)

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption") 
' Obtain an instance of the the class 
' using a key property value.
Set objShare = objWMIService.Get("Win32_EncryptableVolume.DeviceID='\\?\Volume{a2965903-4af0-11e2-be65-806e6f6e6963}\'")

' Obtain an InParameters object specific
' to the method.
Set objInParam = objShare.Methods_("UnlockWithCertificateFile"). _
    inParameters.SpawnInstance_()


' Add the input parameters.
objInParam.Properties_.Item("PathWithFileName") =  "D:\BitLocker.pfx"
objInParam.Properties_.Item("Pin") =  "PinCode

' Execute the method and obtain the return status.
' The OutParameters object in objOutParams
' is created by the provider.
Set objOutParams = objWMIService.ExecMethod("Win32_EncryptableVolume.DeviceID='\\?\Volume{a2965903-4af0-11e2-be65-806e6f6e6963}\'", "UnlockWithCertificateFile", objInParam)

' List OutParams
Wscript.Echo "Out Parameters: "
Wscript.echo "ReturnValue: " & objOutParams.ReturnValue
```

has anyone ever used this method or can anyone see something i may be doing wrong? also i'm using the windows 8 commandline recovery option, i'm not sure if that makes a difference because i have tested calling other methods and wmi and scripting seem to be fully implemented.